# iOS - how to detect all beacons around without using UUID

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon, region-ranging

I am working on iBeacons. Trying to find out all beacons around me.

Like Android, in iOS, we cannot achieve this without specifing "UUID" while searching. 
By using UUID, it is working fine.

is there any better solution to search all beacons around you, without specifying UUID?

I found one solution **RNLBeaconScanner**, which is in **objective c**. RNLBeaconScanner **detecting beacons in ObjC** but **same beacons not detecting in swift**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; You can't.

Longer answer: 
If you specifically are working with iBeacons, you NEED to know their [UUID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clbeaconidentityconstraint/3240598-uuid)s, to pass a valid [CLBeaconIdentityConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clbeaconidentityconstraint) to [startRangingBeacons](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/3240607-startrangingbeacons) method of [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager).

[Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth), which can be used for general BLE scanning, unfortunately [cannot be used to detect iBeacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288211/how-to-get-the-detail-for-beacon-detected-by-cbcentralmanager), because, well, [apple doesn't want you to](https://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html).